# How to change google tag account id dynamically - angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-tag-manager

i am trying to implement google tag manager in my app (angular 5 app)

however, my app is serving a few clients (companies accounts), that access the app from multiples paths e.g:`www.myapp.com/dymamiPath123`  (totally dynamically - cant be hardcode)

i need that change the google tag id per the data that comes from server
(i save each account google tag id in my DB)

i currently have this in my index.html

```
 <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', '** id ***');
</script>
```

how can i change it before\after the app is deployed? 
it is enough to change the id in the function? (not that i know how) 
or change in all the rendered tags?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This look a bit older but I had the same problem. Depending of the referer, same page has to use a GTM or another. This is because same JSP is used for severeal clients.

So I added a variable '${gtmIdentificador}' where I load the GTM. I looks to work.

This using JSP on Java. You can test it with dataslayer pluing on chrome.

```
<script> (function(w,d,s,l,i){
w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${gtmIdentificador}');</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in my application where in different environment(dev/stage/prod) we had different google tag id.
To fix that in script tag, based on domain name dynamically file path keep script in three seperate files

```
gta.script.dev.js
gta.script.stage.js
gta.script.prod.js

<script>
// change to hostname
let domain = window.location.host;
let src = './path/gta.script.prod.js';

if (domain === "stage.domain.name") {
    src = './path/gta.script.stage.js';
}
else if (domain === "prod.domain.name") {
    src = './path/gta.script.prod.js';
}
else if (domain === "stage.domain.name") {
    src = './path/gta.script.prod.js';
}

function addScript(src) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', src);

    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
addScript(src);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont use only one GTM and make a lookup table for the web property you want to send info to?

So you only ll need a variable that has always available the origin of the user (lets call it origin).
And you set all your tag with triggers for specific origins or generic ones but always us a table in order to send hits to different GA accounts depending on the origin.

Finally you can choose to duplicate hits if you want to have a central web property with all the data (use a custom dimension on user level to save the origin). Here is our guru: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/send-google-analytics-tag-multiple-properties/

Hope it helps!